# Correct way to select workbook in currently open spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

Is this the correct way to select a worksheet (Main) in the currently open workbook (i.e. the one that is currently open)

```
'Specify sheet name for Main wb
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")
```

Comment: this code selects worksheet "main" from the workbook where your code is located (from which you run your macro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by currently opened you refered to the one that is currently active (opened and active in your excel window) use: `Set sh1=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")` otherwise as stated by @simoco your current code will select the workbook where your code is placed in.